# Dynamic nav menu boostrap that it is left or right side that related with sreenwidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav menu that has got a lot ul in ul tag so I have to change where it is opened that right side or left side.

And if main menu is bigger than screenwidth then they must be hamburger menu that they are not fit on screen.

I created this js code. It is working and stable. 
something that requires attention.

1- there is a class that's name is ".has-children" in my design

2- if screen bigger than 1070, it can be shown
@media (max-width: 1070px)

so You may need to change relating to your code this code in my js 
if (screenWidth > 1070)
because it will be start after 1070

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var menu = $("#nav").find("ul:first");

    var navbarSticky = $(".navbar.navbar-sticky");//navbar-sticky
    var menubarLeft = $(".site-branding");//logo left
    var menubarRight = $(".toolbar");//toolbar right
    var right = parseInt(menubarRight.css("right").replace("px", "")); // right space of right toolbar
    var oldMenu = menu.html(); //necessary for reset it that configured

    var minWidthSiteMenu = 1070;

    var screenWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
    if (screenWidth > minWidthSiteMenu) {
        menu.html(oldMenu);
        setMenuPosition();
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var screenWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
        if (screenWidth > minWidthSiteMenu) {
            menu.html(oldMenu);
            setMenuPosition();
        }
    });


    function setMenuPosition() {
        var menuFixed = false;
        var humburgerMenuArray = new Array();
        var counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            var result = navbarSticky.width() - menubarLeft.width() - menubarRight.width() - menu.width() - right - 70;// 70 for icon of humburger menu
            if (result < 0) {
                //console.log(menu.find("li").last().html());
                humburgerMenuArray[counter] = $("#nav").find("ul:first > li:last").html();
                counter++;
                $("#nav").find("ul:first > li:last").remove();
                result = navbarSticky.width() - menubarLeft.width() - menubarRight.width() - menu.width() - right;
                menu.css("margin-left", menubarLeft.width() + result / 2 + 20 + "px");
                i = -1;
                menuFixed = true;
            }
            else {
                menu.css("margin-left", menubarLeft.width() + result / 2 + 20 + "px");
                i = 1;
            }
            //console.log(menu);
            //console.log(result);
        }
        if (menuFixed) {
            var imageHamburger = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='none' stroke='currentColor' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' class='feather feather-menu'><line x1='3' y1='12' x2='21' y2='12'></line><line x1='3' y1='6' x2='21' y2='6'></line><line x1='3' y1='18' x2='21' y2='18'></line></svg>";
            var humburgerMenu = "<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' style='padding-top: 26px !important;' class='menu-toggle'>" + imageHamburger + "</a>";
            humburgerMenu += "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
            var counterHumburger = humburgerMenuArray.length;
            humburgerMenuArray.forEach(function () {
                var hasChildren = humburgerMenuArray[counterHumburger - 1].search("sub-menu");
                if (hasChildren === -1) {
                    humburgerMenu += "<li>";
                }
                else {
                    humburgerMenu += "<li class='has-children'>";
                }
                humburgerMenu += humburgerMenuArray[counterHumburger - 1];
                humburgerMenu += "</li>";
                //console.log(humburgerMenuArray[counterHumburger - 1]);
                counterHumburger--;
            });
            humburgerMenu += "</ul>";
            humburgerMenu += "</li>";
            menu.append(humburgerMenu);
            //console.log(menu.html());
        }
        $("#nav").css("visibility", "visible");
        //set setSubMenuPositionLeftRightSide
        setSubMenuPositionLeftRightSide();
    }

    /* Menu Position Left or Right Side */
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = "li.left-arrow > a::after {border-left: 0 solid !important;border-right: .32em solid !important;}";
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    var menuLeftPositionIsOk = false;
    var nextMenuPositon = 0;
    var zIndex = 10000;

    function setSubMenuPositionLeftRightSide() {
        var screenWidth = $(window).outerWidth(); //outerWidth is very important because it is not contain to spage of scroll that overflow
        //console.log(screenWidth);
        //reset all rel attr - its name is rel-menu-position
        $("#nav > ul").each(function (i) {
            $(this).find("ul").removeAttr('rel-menu-position');
        });

        $("#nav > ul > li > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
            menuLeftPositionIsOk = false;
            //nextMenuPositon = 0; // it is not necessary
            zIndex = 10000;
        }, function (c) { });

        var menuId = 0;
        if (screenWidth > minWidthSiteMenu) {

            $(".has-children").hover(function (e) {

                zIndex++;
                $(e.currentTarget).css("zIndex", zIndex);
                //console.log($(e.currentTarget).css("zIndex"));
                menuPositionCalculate(e, screenWidth);

            },
                function (c) {

                    menuLeftPositionIsOk = false;//this is very important for other sub menu that you have change it... 
                    $(c.currentTarget).css("zIndex", 'auto');
                    $(c.currentTarget).removeClass("left-arrow");
                    //console.log("menu is closed");
                });
        }
    }

    function menuPositionCalculate(e, screenWidth) {

        var menuPosition = $(e.target).offset().left + $(e.currentTarget).width() + $(e.currentTarget).find('ul').outerWidth();
        //console.log("menuPosition " + menuPosition);

        // 25px space left side
        if (nextMenuPositon - $(e.currentTarget).find('ul').outerWidth() - 25 < 0) { 
            menuLeftPositionIsOk = false;
            //console.log("RESET - left side - if " + menuPosition + " >> " + screenWidth);
        }

        if ($(e.currentTarget).find('ul').first().attr('rel-menu-position') === 'left') {
            menuLeftPositionIsOk = true;
        }
        if ($(e.currentTarget).find('ul').first().attr('rel-menu-position') === 'right') {
            menuLeftPositionIsOk = false;
        }
        // 25px space right side
        if (menuPosition + 25 > screenWidth || 
            menuLeftPositionIsOk ||
            nextMenuPositon + 25 > screenWidth) {
            menuPosition = $(e.target).offset().left + $(e.currentTarget).width() + $(e.currentTarget).find('ul').outerWidth();
            menuLeftPositionIsOk = true;
            nextMenuPositon = menuLeftSidePosition(e);
            //console.log("left side if " + menuPosition + " >> " + screenWidth);
            $(e.currentTarget).addClass("left-arrow");
            $(e.currentTarget).find('ul').first().attr('rel-menu-position', 'left');
        } else {
            $(e.currentTarget).removeClass("left-arrow");
            $(e.currentTarget).find('ul').first().attr('rel-menu-position', 'right');
        }
    }

    function menuLeftSidePosition(e) {
        //20px come over to parent menu
        var menuPositionLeft = $(e.target).offset().left - $(e.currentTarget).find('ul').first().outerWidth() + 20;
        $(e.currentTarget).find('ul').first().offset({ "left": menuPositionLeft });
        return menuPositionLeft;
    }

});
    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide your code with HTML, or it would be great if you can provide fiddle link.

Comment: I used  "unishop template". you can search on the internet.  
 >> http://themes.rokaux.com/unishop/v3.2.1/template-1/index.html you can add this code at the end with <script></script> tag. And you can add more li.... so you can see result... sometimes, version can be change. it is  v3.2.1 now.

Comment: I fixed some errors.